How would humans behave if resources were infinite (a "mutt world")?
Below is a vignette where humans have unlimited resources, some force creates tractors out of thin air for humans to hit a button and run agriculture etc.
It seems like we've covered most of the significant aspects of life in this Mutt World scenario, given the parameters you've set. However, there are a few more subtle points worth considering:

1. Emotional and Psychological Health

Emotional Stagnation:

With humans doing the bare minimum to survive and no significant emotional challenges or aspirations, psychological health might shift into a new equilibrium.
People might experience some form of mild contentment, but any deep emotional engagement would be rare. Depression could still occur, but it might take on a more existential form, as the world offers no compelling reason to strive or grow.
The "mood" of society would likely lean toward a monotonous baseline, with individuals content in their place but not deeply fulfilled.




2. Technology's Role

Technological Stagnation:

Technology would serve primarily as a tool for convenience rather than advancement. With divine influence providing for basic needs, there would be no incentive to push the boundaries of technology.
Technology might still exist in the form of gadgets, entertainment, or simple conveniences, but it wouldn’t evolve in the way it does in our world. Advanced systems like space exploration or cutting-edge AI would be entirely absent.




3. Communication and Social Interaction

Limited Social Networks:

In a world where people do the minimum to survive, social interaction would also be minimal. There wouldn't be a need for large, complex social networks or gatherings, as personal relationships wouldn’t evolve past a simple, functional level.
Interaction might be limited to basic needs fulfillment or running scams, with very little cultural exchange. Media might exist, but it would be so basic and inoffensive that it wouldn’t serve as a meaningful social bonding tool.




4. Creativity and Artistic Expression

Art as an Afterthought:

Art might still exist as a form of personal expression, but it would lack depth or social relevance. Since there would be no significant challenges to overcome, creative works wouldn’t explore profound themes of existence, struggle, or aspiration.
People would create for the sake of creating but would lack a driving force or motivation to innovate or push boundaries. Most artistic efforts would be designed to maintain equilibrium and avoid anything controversial.




5. Identity and Individuality

Uniformity:

The extreme social homogeneity resulting from the lack of conflict, challenge, or aspiration might lead to a significant degree of uniformity in human identity.
People might not have the drive to express unique individuality or personal identity in a meaningful way. Fashion, personality, and even gender might become more fluid or irrelevant as people adapt to the minimalist nature of existence.




6. Religion and Spirituality

Religious Conformity:

In a world dominated by divine control, all humans would likely adhere to the same worldview, as there would be no competing ideologies or belief systems.
Spirituality would likely be viewed as a passive acceptance of the divine will, with little to no engagement in religious practices beyond recognition of the divine as an omnipotent presence.
There would be no religious diversity, as the divine presence would preclude any significant dissent or divergence in belief.




7. Environmental Changes and Natural Events

Divine Control Over Natural Disasters:

If the divine can fix pollution and manage resources, natural disasters might also be prevented or minimized. There would be no extreme weather events, earthquakes, or other natural catastrophes unless the divine allowed it for a purpose.
Even if there were natural events, the human impact would be so minimal that there wouldn't be any real societal breakdown as a result.




8. Global Interaction and Travel

Minimal Travel or Interaction Between Groups:

The idea of globalism or even large-scale travel would be rendered irrelevant. Most people would stay within a limited radius, and there would be no significant effort to explore beyond their immediate environment.
Different groups or regions wouldn't develop distinct cultures or identities, as the lack of meaningful social or economic differences would prevent the kind of diversity that usually drives cultural evolution.




9. Sense of Time and Legacy

Time as an Abstract Concept:

Without a focus on progress, work, or long-term goals, people might experience a lack of urgency. Time could become an abstract, almost irrelevant concept.
The notion of legacy—leaving something behind—would have little meaning, as the divine's intervention ensures that everything necessary is provided, leaving no room for individuals to be remembered for their achievements.




10. Technology's Role in Daily Life

Minimal Use of High-Tech Tools:

Given the divine control, technological tools would be rudimentary at best, perhaps limited to simple gadgets for personal convenience or entertainment, such as music players or small devices to manage minimal tasks.
Complex tools like smartphones or computers might be seen as novelties, used only by the "nerdy" subcultures you mentioned, but they would have no deep impact on daily life.




In summary, I believe we’ve covered the majority of the aspects of life in this Mutt World scenario. The underlying theme is the absence of conflict, scarcity, or struggle, and the effects that this would have on human motivation, behavior, and societal structures. The divine presence would strip humanity of its drive for progress or change, resulting in a stagnant but functional world, where people simply exist without pushing the boundaries of their existence.
The main distinction here is that this world, while peaceful and stable, would lack the dynamic characteristics that make human society so varied and complex today. It would be a world focused entirely on basic survival, comfort, and minimal interaction—one where innovation, conflict, and meaningful progress have no place.

Does sexual desire exist? (i.e. => jealousy) How does it manifest?

Its the same as the real world and everything happens. Sexual desire is not a major conflict in the real world and if significant conflicts happened I would guess the aforementioned scams would be involved. At the same time it takes no effort to survive and there would be no urgency to anything.
Because of muttification race will not exist but if a white person ended up there the reaction may be hostile.

Greetings! I'm not exactly certain quite what your question is. Please take a moment to review the [tour] and [help] and find out what WB.SE is all about before you ask questions. While you've got some interesting ideas, they don't appear to coalesce into a single, focused, problem solving type question.

I'm not sure I get point 1 as written. In paradise, people are known to create havoc - i.e. they tend to get discontented with Eden, it gets boring and they rebel against it. I suppose that this would depend on their conditioning and the constraints they believe are holding them. Some will try to build, some wreck the building ("only playing") - this would lead to conflict inevitably. Does sexual desire exist? (i.e. => jealousy) How does it manifest? Is each individual "in their own universe" isolated from others to prevent conflict? Are they all neutered? Please clarify how this works.

Welcome to WBSE. "How would humans behave if resources were infinite" - this is a story-based question, as it turns out. We can help you build the world as far as mechanics, and justification for certain behaviors, but we can't tell you outright what behavior will take place because that's not something we can authoritatively tell you. The answer is "whatever the story requires".

I would like to echo my fellow World Builders - there is potential here for a valid question (and a fun one at that), but as written, it seems like you have posted a reply or response from someone else reviewing your world and you are wanting us to assist? This is not what we do. If you can narrow it down to a proper question, we can help.

We are already in your world. We can already make all the goods everyone might reasonably want. That’s why 80% of the economy is services, which can’t be manufactured by machines and don’t benefit from unlimited resources. The economy doesn’t change much if the cost of the 20% that’s not services reduces.

Close close close close close. (a) I haven't the SLIGHTEST IDEA what a "mutt world" is. I tried to google it without success. (b) Humanity evolved in a competitive environment. According to your rules, divinity removed everything it is to be human. A world full of biological robots - no humans. And then you ask if sexuality would exist? It's your world. Do you want it or not? (c) We have a [tag:review-my-idea] tag, but it has really specific rules ... (*Continued*)

... that you must follow or your post will be arbitrarily closed. (d) It would help immensely if you carefully read the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask] to understand the purpose of this stack and its limitations. If what you're looking for is (1) a discussion or (2) general commentary about your ideas... you are in exactly the wrong place. We're more than willing to help you create your world - but you've already done that.

BTW, I've gotta ask... why on earth did you tag your post [tag:magic]?

This is a answered question. We had what amounted to "infinite" ressources regarding energy with oil since the 60s... the result was - a flying apart of society, as the economic constraints where the glue holding the old world together. Freedom bloomed, but duties were neglected and strange new sandcastles errected. Also, all infinite ressources seem to lead to buildup of infinite garbage, never delt with before (in the air of all things), and the inability to handle that strangled that.

This seemed like it was well on the way to being a successful "internal-consistency" or "fact check" type problem, and could be reworked.  For example, I'd note that you're confusing prey and predator here: the abundance with the clever exploiters who recreate scarcity.  Infinite resources would make for huge creativity - followed by legions of tireless enforcers to seek it out and prosecute it for offending public morals.  The conformity comes with the latter, not the former.  On a broader basis, creating currency and prosecuting the poor until they have to serve the rich to live.
